# Bootstrap 2 bug? [class*="span"] weird issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

After 3 hours digging I finally found the cause of a weird issue I'm having with a Wordpress theme.

Whenever I add a tag to an article that contains the word "span" (e.g Espana), it breaks the layout.

Wordpress adds the class to the article "tag-espana" as expected, although Bootstrap stylesheet applies some rules to it, ruining the layout.

This should be caused by the following selector which is extensively used in Bootstrap 2:

```
[class*="span"]
```

Is this a known bug? I couldn't find any info about this so I have some doubts. Any idea on how could I fix this without editing bootstrap source files?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of this happening?

Comment: It would be too complicated unfortunately, but it's just like I explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody expects the `span`ish inquisition

Yes, that seems like a bug with this selector. You could modify it by adding a restriction:

```
[class*="span"]:not([class*="tag-"])
```

or

```
[class*="span"]:not([class*="espana"])
```

but that won't be understood by IE7 and IE8 (if TB2 is compatible with IE7 in the first place, can't remember)

It would be better to override systematically:

```
[class*="span"] {
  property: value-in-TB2;
}
[class*="espana"] {
  property: nope-override;
}
```

but as you wrote, it may be used too much by TB2 to be possible to do that...

Or see how your `tag-espana` elements are styled and override everything that isn't wanted.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's a possible solution, although it would require editing core files (quite a lot). I was thinking how about a jQuery solution that removes every classname containing "tag-" plus any word containing "span". Would that be possible?

Comment: Or you could do it server-side via a WP hook maybe?

Comment: Mmm even better, not really sure how though, would you be able to provide an example? I'll accept your answer in the meantime.

Comment: I haven't done any PHP for nearly 2 years so nope :) But there's [Filter references](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) (search for "tag") on WP Codex, many tutorials on hooks (check that its method is still OK for WP > 3.4) and a SE site for WP

Comment: No worries. For now it seems to be fixed by simply adding:

`[class*="tag-"] {
 float:none!important;
 margin-left:0!important;
}`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah yes. Maybe you can add `[class*="tag-"][class*="span"] {}` as it only aims at class names having both span AND tag- in their name. And with more specificity, you can remove `!important` if it wasn't already in TB2 (I bet it was though)